# Count unique values of "X" where all instances of "X" are associated with the same assigned value "Y"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Say I have a table like the following:

```
X   Y
1 TRUE
1 TRUE
1 FALSE
1 TRUE
2 FALSE
2 FALSE
2 FALSE
2 FALSE
3 TRUE
3 TRUE
3 TRUE
3 FALSE
```

- `1` is associated with both `TRUE` and `FALSE`.
- `2` is associated only with `FALSE`.
- `3` is associated with both `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

So the result would be a count of one "X" value (that being `2`), which is associated with only a single "Y" value.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You could just make an IF statement on the next column to test if X = 2, and Y = FALSE, return TRUE on the next column, and copy that down the row. Any with "TRUE" are the one you wanted. If you need a "count" of those, at the bottom of the row, you can do a COUNT of all the TRUE on that column... but if you can post an edit with what you expect to see, we can probably help you better as I'm just guessing on what you may want.

Comment: I've made an edit which should clarify things

Comment: so you want to run a check for any value in x and get the first x which only contains 1 y (regardless of true/false)... 1 contains true and false and will be skipped. 2 contains only fasle (also would count if all y were true) then stop here and output x (in this case 2)... did i got that correctly?

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right, you want to something like this: (assuming x is in `A1` and y in `B1` having `C` as helper column)

```
C1: =MIN(C2:C100)
C2: =B2
C3: =IF(A2=A3,IF(A3=A4,IF(B3=C2,B3,"N/A"),IF(B3=C2,A3,"N/A")),B3)
```

Then simply copy down the code in C3 (adjust C1 to fit your needs).